# Host Wordpress blog and static websites on Amazon S3

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3

sIs there a way I can host my wordpress blog and static website on Amazon s3 ?

Answer (score 3):

[As a matter of fact, maybe](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/02/host-your-static-website-on-amazon-s3.html).  They just announced this last month.  That blog post has all of the relevant details, though it should be noted that it's intended for *static* content, not the dynamic content of a full Wordpress installation.  Consider using a different blogging engine, one that produces static HTML.

Answer (score -2):

Amazon S3 won't run a Wordpress blog. There could be some plugins to generate a static website out of a running installation of Wordpress, but I won't recommend this.